# A name for the directional derivative with respect to a unit vector?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I finally came up with a reasonable justification for not requiring the reference vector of the directional derivative to be of unit length.  But that is another discussion.

This has bothered me for a long time.  Partial derivatives in Cartesian form are directional derivatives with respect to the standard (unit) basis vectors.  If I rotate my coordinate system so that one axis shares the direction in which I am differentiating, the partial derivative with respect to the corresponding coordinate is a directional derivative with respect to the new (unit) basis vector.

If I want to know how much a scalar potential changes with respect to ark length in a given direction, I find the dot product of the gradient with a unit vector in that direction.

In some introductory calculus books the directional derivative is defined to be with respect to a unit vector.  There are many places in which the directional derivative with respect to a unit vector is valuable.  I there a good name for that special kind of directional derivative?

I believe some authors call the directional derivative operator with respect to a unit vector the unit vector.  In other words the vector is the operator.  But that makes my head spin.

Comment: As far as I know, there isn't a special name for the directional derivative when using a unit vector. In fact, I believe it is the modal choice for directional derivatives. That said, I have seen other literature use non unit vectors, but I was of the opinion that this is unusual. I could be wrong, however.

Comment: Not according to Misner, Thorne and Wheeler;  Bernard Schutz and C. H. Edwards, Jr.  The directional derivative is $D_{\Delta\mathfrak{x}}f\left[\mathfrak{x}\right]=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{f\left[\mathfrak{x}+t\Delta\mathfrak{x}\right]-f\left[\mathfrak{x}\right]}{t}$, according to them.

Comment: Oh well. I guess I was wrong then.

Comment: Wrong only in so much as the "big boys" stole your ball. The first definition of the directional derivative I learned was yours.  AKA the sane one.

Comment: Can you please point to me the discussion about the justification (of not requiring unit vector length)? I am also confused. Many thanks!